# Variable PHP inicializada por parámetros GET

Tags: php, get

Tengo una aplicación de PHP 5 funcionando en un servidor , pero al trasladarlo a otro servidor el código falla. Me he dado cuenta que el código original hace una petición GET calidad.php?id_alarma=1754 pero en calidad.php aunque se usa la variable $id_alarma no se inicializa en ninguna parte del código. Es decir que recoge el parámetro del GET de alguna manera. ¿Cómo puede ser?

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen). Sin código nadie podrá ayudarte...

Comment: Hay una directiva en PHP llamada "register_globals" que, si está activada, permite que las variables se registren automáticamente como variables globales de PHP. Esto significa que si en una página se hace una petición GET o POST con un parámetro, se puede acceder a ese parámetro como una variable global sin necesidad de inicializarla.
Sin embargo, esta función está obsoleta y se recomienda no usarla, ya que puede ser una fuente de inseguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que la variable $id_alarma esté recogiendo su valor a través de la función superglobal $_GET en PHP. La función $_GET es una variable predefinida en PHP que contiene los valores enviados en la URL a través del método GET. Por lo tanto, si su aplicación está haciendo una petición GET como calidad.php?id_alarma=1754, entonces puede recuperar el valor 1754 de la siguiente manera:

```
$id_alarma = $_GET['id_alarma'];
```

Después de esto, puede utilizar la variable $id_alarma en su código como desee. Tenga en cuenta que es importante validar los valores recibidos a través de $_GET o $_POST para asegurarse de que sean seguros y apropiados para su aplicación.

Es posible que en su antiguo servidor la variable $_GET estuviera activa y funcionando correctamente, mientras que en el nuevo servidor puede estar desactivada o no estar configurada correctamente. Es recomendable que verifique la configuración y la versión de PHP en el nuevo servidor para asegurarse de que todas las funciones y variables superglobales estén disponibles y configuradas correctamente.